# Pywin32 how to replace text in entire word document

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32, pywinauto

I am having trouble replacing words in the entire text document. The following code works to replace words in the main paragraphs but not when text is present in text boxes.

```
wdFindContinue = 1
wdReplaceAll = 2
word.Selection.Find.Execute(find_str, True, True, False, False, False, True, wdFindContinue, False, replace_str, wdReplaceAll)
```

Is there a way to replace words in the entire document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See the article by Word MVPs on [Using a macro to replace text wherever it appears in a document](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm).

> A collaborative effort of MVP’s Doug Robbins and Greg Maxey with
> enhancements by Peter Hewett and Jonathan West
>
> Using the Find or Replace utility on the Edit menu you can find or
> replace text "almost" anywhere it appears in the document. If you
> record that action however, the scope or "range" of the resulting
> recorded macro will only act on the text contained in the body of the
> document (or more accurately, it will only act on the part of the
> document that contains the insertion point). This means that if the
> insertion point is located in the main body of the document when your
> macro is executed it will have no effect on text that is in the
> headers or footers of the document, for example, or in a textbox,
> footnotes, or any other area that is outside the main body of the
> document.
>
> *Even the Find and Replace utility has a shortcoming. For example, text*
> *in a textbox located in a header or footer is outside the scope of the*
> *Find and Replace utility search range.*

`***`

> To use a macro to find or replace text anywhere in a document, it is
> necessary to loop through each individual part of the document. In
> VBA, these parts are called StoryRanges. Each StoryRange is identified
> by a unique wdStoryType constant.
>
> There are eleven different wdStoryType constants that can form the
> StoryRanges (or parts) of a document (ok, a few more in later versions
> of Word, but they have no bearing in this discussion). Simple
> documents may contain only one or two StoryRanges, while more complex
> documents may contain more. The wdStoryTypes that have a role in find
> and replace are:
>
> wdCommentsStory, wdEndnotesStory, wdEvenPagesFooterStory,
> wdEvenPagesHeaderStory, wdFirstPageFooterStory,
> wdFirstPageHeaderStory, wdFootnotesStory, wdMainTextStory,
> wdPrimaryFooterStory, wdPrimaryHeaderStory, and wdTextFrameStory.
>
> The complete code to find or replace text anywhere is a bit complex.
> Accordingly, let’s take it a step at a time to better illustrate the
> process. In many cases the simpler code is sufficient for getting the
> job done.

### Step 1

> The following code loops through each StoryRange in the active
> document and replaces the specified .Text with .Replacement.Text:

```
Sub FindAndReplaceFirstStoryOfEachType()
  Dim rngStory As Range
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With rngStory.Find
      .Text = "find text"
      .Replacement.Text = "I'm found"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next rngStory
End Sub
```

> (Note for those already familiar with VBA: whereas if you use
> Selection.Find, you have to specify all of the Find and Replace
> parameters, such as .Forward = True, because the settings are
> otherwise taken from the Find and Replace dialog's current settings,
> which are “sticky”, this is not necessary if using [Range].Find –
> where the parameters use their default values if you don't specify
> their values in your code).
>
> The simple macro above has shortcomings. It only acts on the "first"
> StoryRange of each of the eleven StoryTypes (i.e., the first header,
> the first textbox, and so on). While a document only has one
> wdMainTextStory StoryRange, it can have multiple StoryRanges in some
> of the other StoryTypes. If, for example, the document contains
> sections with un-linked headers and footers, or if it contains
> multiple textboxes, there will be multiple StoryRanges for those
> StoryTypes and the code will not act upon the second and subsequent
> StoryRanges. To even further complicate matters, if your document
> contains unlinked headers or footers and one of the headers or footers
> are empty then VBA can have trouble "jumping" that empty header or
> footer and process subsequent headers and footers.

The page has more, but the above should help.

Comment: Yes, this information was helpful as I had to loop through the next storyrange.

Comment: The Word MVP pages, although dated, are a valuable resource. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA.htm